# MySQL INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE FROM DIFFERENT TABLE

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery, on-duplicate-key

I'm using node.js with MySQL and i have two table like Bookings and Places to make a parking API

I'm trying to book a place on Table Bookings and update field Places.isAvailable (type Boolean)  in a same query like:

```
"INSERT INTO Bookings (userId, placeId) VALUES (?,?) 
 SELECT isAvailable FROM Places 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Places.isAvailable='1';"
```

I get a syntax error from MySQL

Can you tell me what's wrong with my query ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: 1) Either `INSERT .. VALUES` or `INSERT .. SELECT`. Not both. 2) INSERT may insert in one table only. And hence update on duplicate - in the same table only. Use trigger logic or perform insertion in stored procedure.

Comment: thanks a lot Akina !

Comment: @Akina can you show me a exemple of stored procedure with this both query like INSERT AND UPDATE ?

Comment: In stored procedure you simply check the presence of according row with SELECT query in IF or CASE condition.